# Eclipse CDT Code Completion Issue

Tags: c++, eclipse, intellisense, code-completion, eclipse-cdt

For some reason the code completion for the Eclipse CDT I'm running (in Ubuntu linux) isn't working properly. Every time I include a library nothing pops up. Is there any reason why this could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including a header in your source code is not enough. You need to tell the indexer where to look for the header. To do so, you need to go to your project's properties, navigate to the `C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols` item. In the `Includes` tab, add the folder containing your headers for the `GNU C++` language. You may also need to define a few symbols in the `Symbols` tab if your library needs it.

Now you'll just have to wait for the indexer to do it's thing and auto-completion should start working. Keep in mind that the indexer isn't perfect and complicated C++ headers like the STL can confuse it pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks. Done and done. 

As far as defining the symbols, I'm coming from Java, so I don't really know much about that. What exactly would I need to define new symbols for?

Comment: You probably don't need it but some headers could change their implementation based on [preprocessor directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). For example, if a header has a `#ifdef FOOBAR` directive and the indexer hasn't encountered the equivalent `#define FOOBAR` directive then whatever is included within the `#ifdef` section won't be indexed. You won't really need to do this very often if ever (probably shouldn't have mentionned it).

Comment: This works great for C++ projects, but what about Android Projects that include C/C++ in their native libraries?

Comment: @Kevin I'm not at all familliar with Android but I'm going to guess that there's some JNI-ish thingy going on here to have C/C++ in a Java project. I sadly don't have a clue if it's even possible to add C++ settings to a Java-ish project. My totally random recommendation would be to split your porject into two (one for Android and one for Java).

Comment: @Ze Blob - Do you know how I could then either have some sort of 'symbolic reference' to the files in the C++ project? It would be great if I could simply keep it as a Java project and either, have C++ settings pane or have the C++ files still in the Java project, but they're simply linked somehow to the C++ project.

Comment: @Kevin I've done a bit of screwing around and I think the best solution would be to segregate your cpp files into a folder and create a new CDT project in that folder (DON'T use your java project root). It's a bit of an ugly hack but it **looks** like it works and has no effect on the original java project. Do take the necessary precautions (backups) before attempting this. If you're on a linux system you could also create a seperate folder for your CDT project and add a symbolic link back to your C++ files. I haven't tested this though but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it cannot find the headers. You have to specify the include paths in the Includes section of your tool settings for the project. Other method's may prevent eclipse from finding the headers even when gcc can find them.